# reset and set a timeout on mousemove to do something after inactivity

Tags: javascript

I have a bit of code that after an hour of inactivity to navigate to a different page.

```
var NavigateTimer;

document.addEventListener("mousemove", resetTimer);

function setTimer ()
{
    NavigateTimer = setTimeout(setNav, 5000);
}

function resetTimer ()
{
    clearTimeout(NavigateTimer);
    setTimer();
}

function setNav ()
{
    console.log("Navigate")
}

setTimer();
```

Here after 5 seconds setNav gets called. If there is a mousemove event I want to clear/reset the timeout and start a new one. This works but I'm worried that clearing and setting a timeout with mousemove will create too many timeouts since I think clearing doesn't remove it entirely.

Is this true and could that create an issue or is this something I shouldn't worry about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a single timer to repeatedly (but not too often) check the time elapsed since the last activity. Navigation will delete this timer, so there is no need to call clearInterval at all.

```js
let lastActivity = new Date();
const maxWait = 15 * 1000; // Inactivity interval before navigation, in msec

setInterval(() => {
  if (new Date().valueOf() - lastActivity.valueOf() > maxWait) {
    console.log("Navigate");
    location.href = "https://www.google.com";
  }
}, 5000);

document.addEventListener("mousemove", () => {
  console.log("Mouse moved");
  lastActivity = new Date();
});
```

Comment: Seems to work thank you! Is the 15 * 1000 just for readability?

Comment: Yes. You could write 15000, or if you want one hour, 3600000.

Comment: I ended up adding something else I found on here to it.
`
lastActivity = new Date();
scheduled = false;

document.addEventListener("mousemove", () => {
 if(!scheduled)
 {
  scheduled = true;
  
  console.log("mouse moved")
  lastActivity = new Date();
  
  setTimeout(() => {
   scheduled = false;
  }, 10000)
 }
});
`

So it doesn't update the date all that often.

Answer (score 0):

i think this one is better. clear and simple

```js
var mTimer;

const setNav_ = function(){
  console.log("Navigate");
}

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(){
  clearTimeout(mTimer);
  mTimer = setTimeout(setNav_, 5000);
});
```

Comment: This is nice but I don't think adding an event listener on the `document` is necessary since the `onmousemove` event already exists on the `document`. I think something like the following would work.
    
`const foo = () => {console.log('yo yo yo')}`
`document.onmousemove = foo;`